# ios google sign-in, How can I get user image url?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, google-signin

I am working on iOS/Swift google sign-in. I made a demo in github. 
My demo project: https://github.com/tanggod/GoogleSignIn.git

According to google(https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_profile_data#a8e229bffe211894473058c4ba247553c), the user image url can be fetched like this:

- (NSURL *) imageURLWithDimension:      (NSUInteger)    dimension
  Gets the user's profile image URL for the given dimension in pixels for each side of the square.

But, when I try to get imageURLWithDimension(120), the App always crash. I have been struggling on this for half an day and still don't know why.
Anybody can help me. thank you very much.

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
    print("=== UIViewController sign in")

    if (error == nil) {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        //let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let name = user.profile.name
        let email = user.profile.email
        if user.profile.hasImage{
            // crash here !!!!!!!! cannot get imageUrl here, why?
            // let imageUrl = user.profile.imageURLWithDimension(120)
            let imageUrl = signIn.currentUser.profile.imageURLWithDimension(120)
            print(" image url: ", imageUrl.absoluteString)
        }
        // ...
        print(" userId: ", userId)
        //            print(" idToken: ", idToken)
        print(" name: ", name)
        print(" email: ", email)
        labelName.text = name
        labelEmail.text = email
    } else {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

the crash data is as follows:

```
2015-09-30 18:54:46.662 GoogleLogin[96614:] <GMR/INFO> App measurement v.1100000 started
2015-09-30 18:54:46.675 GoogleLogin[96614:5594982] Successfully configured [SignIn].
2015-09-30 18:54:46.675 GoogleLogin[96614:5594982] Failed to configure [].
2015-09-30 18:54:46.676 GoogleLogin[96614:5594982] Subspecs not present, so not configured [Analytics, AdMob, AppInvite, CloudMessaging, Maps].
2015-09-30 18:54:46.676 GoogleLogin[96614:5594982] Subspecs expected to be present [SignIn, Measurement].
2015-09-30 18:54:46.706 GoogleLogin[96614:] <GMR/INFO> Network status has changed. code, status: 2, Connected
=== UIViewController sign in
2015-09-30 18:54:49.335 GoogleLogin[96614:5594982] -[NSURL isFIFEUrl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe248c335c0
2015-09-30 18:56:46.968 GoogleLogin[96614:5594982] -[NSURL isFIFEUrl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe248f11f20
2015-09-30 18:56:46.973 GoogleLogin[96614:5594982] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL isFIFEUrl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe248f11f20'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102304f65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104927deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010230d58d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010225af7a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010225ab28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   GoogleLogin                         0x0000000101db6214 -[GIDProfileData imageURLWithDimension:] + 75
    6   GoogleLogin                         0x0000000101d29d0d _TFC11GoogleLogin14ViewController6signInfS0_FTGSQCSo9GIDSignIn_16didSignInForUserGSQCSo13GIDGoogleUser_9withErrorGSQCSo7NSError__T_ + 2541
    7   GoogleLogin                         0x0000000101d2aa98 _TToFC11GoogleLogin14ViewController6signInfS0_FTGSQCSo9GIDSignIn_16didSignInForUserGSQCSo13GIDGoogleUser_9withErrorGSQCSo7NSError__T_ + 88
    8   GoogleLogin                         0x0000000101dbdeb8 __37-[GIDSignIn addCallDelegateCallback:]_block_invoke + 123
    9   GoogleLogin                         0x0000000101db5ab6 -[GIDCallbackQueue fire] + 147
    10  GoogleLogin                         0x0000000101dbdacb __38-[GIDSignIn addDecodeIdTokenCallback:]_block_invoke_2 + 385
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001053eaef9 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010540b49b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001053f334b _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001022653e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102226939 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102225e98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001066b5ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001034b0676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  GoogleLogin                         0x0000000101d2c36d main + 109
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010543f92d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

And it says signIn.currentUser.profile.imageURLWithDimension(120) is invalid expression:
[image]

Comment: I have almost the exact same code in my project, using a value of `200` works. Are you unable to give me details about the crash?

Comment: thank you @ajmccall , I added the crash log and updated the post. I tried 200, it didn't work for me.

Comment: Which version of Google's SDK are you using? Are you using cocoapods to manage it?

It's looks like a typo somewhere `[NSURL isFIFEUrl]` should probably be `[NSURL isFILEUrl]:`

Comment: Yes, I use cocoapods.  pod 'Google/SignIn' . But I am using swift, where to write [NSURL isFIFEUrl] ?

Comment: Version? I'm using `Google (1.0.7)` and `GoogleSignIn (2.2.0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91018/discussion-between-ajmccall-and-user9527).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly like @ajmccall said, a typo error!

But you may workaround it by category NSURL.

New an Objective-C class:

NSURL+FILE.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSURL (FILE)
- (BOOL) isFIFEUrl;
@end
```

NSURL+FILE.m

## import "NSURL+FILE.h"

```
@implementation  NSURL (FILE)
- (BOOL) isFIFEUrl {
    return [self isFileURL];
}

@end
```

Comment: You rock!. The crash is gone and I can get the image url. thanks @pinxue

Answer (score 19):

For Objective C :

```
if (user.profile.hasImage)
{
    NSURL *url = [user.profile imageURLWithDimension:100];
    NSLog(@"url : %@",url);
}
```

For Swift :

```
if user.profile.hasImage
{
    let pic = user.profile.imageURLWithDimension(100) 
    Print(pic)
}
```

***Note : 100 is the dimension. Its depend on your requirement.***

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3**

```
let dimension = round(imageSize.width * UIScreen.main.scale)
let pic = userInfo.profile.imageURL(withDimension: dimension)
```

OR

```
let dimension = round(100 * UIScreen.main.scale)
let pic = userInfo.profile.imageURL(withDimension: dimension)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug in `GoogleSign 1.10` pod, <strike>and it's a ***typo*** bug at that</strike>. They are calling `[NSURL isFIFEUrl]` when they probably be calling `[NSURL isFILEUrl]`. (Ho ho ho that is hilarious!)

Simply downgrade to `Google/Sign 1.0.7` and it will work.

Comment: downgrade to GoogleSign 2.2.0. but compile failed: Use of unresolved identifier 'GGLContext'. Still trying.

Comment: Hi, change your Podfile to read

`pod 'Google/SignIn', '1.0.7'`

and type `pod install`.

Comment: Hi ajmccall, I tried SDK 2.2.0 and 1.0.7, neither of them works for me. Pinxue's solution works for me. I know you spent lot of time on this issue, but I have to choose Pinxue's solution. Anyway, thank you so much for your efforts.

Comment: Alright, but you're going to need to learn how `pod` works very soon.

Answer (score 2):

Run `pod update` to get 2.3.1 of the SDK.

Background info if you care: It's actually *not* a typo, even though it looks like one. Version 2.3 of the Google sign-in library makes use of another library -- `libGIPNSURL+FIFE.a` -- that was accidentally omitted in version 2.3.0.

Comment: Thanks @todd. In the future, what is the best way to raise an issue with Google's pods?

Answer (score 0):

Are the Subspecs messages just warnings or errors; have this atm:

2015-10-06 18:21:44.289 Blotter[691:739797] Configuring subspecs failed @ CloudMessaging
2015-10-06 18:21:44.311 Blotter[691:739797] Successfully configured [].
2015-10-06 18:21:44.312 Blotter[691:739797] Failed to configure [CloudMessaging].
2015-10-06 18:21:44.312 Blotter[691:739797] Subspecs not present, so not configured [Analytics, AdMob, SignIn, AppInvite].
2015-10-06 18:21:44.312 Blotter[691:739797] Subspecs expected to be present [Measurement].