# iOS google login profileImageURL

Tags: ios, xcode7

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *userId = user.userID;
    NSString *idToken = user.authentication.idToken;
    NSString *name = user.profile.name;
    NSString *email = user.profile.email;
    //NSString *Url = user.profile.imageURL;
}
```

I tried to get google login user details.
How to get profileImageUrl?
any help will be apricated.thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get user image through user id in Google plus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406756/how-to-get-user-image-through-user-id-in-google-plus)

Answer (score 0):

Google has defined a method to get Profile image URLs for `iOS` API. That method is `-(NSURL *) imageURLWithDimension:(NSUInteger) dimension`. You only need to do the following:

Use this code after signing in:

```
 if(user.profile.hasImage)
{
    NSURL *imageURL = [user.profile imageURLWithDimension(50)]; //Give your desired dimenion in parameter.
}
```

This is defined in [Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_profile_data.html#a8e229bffe211894473058c4ba247553c).

If you get an unexpected `FIFEURL error` as some users have in the past, See this [already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871484/ios-google-sign-in-how-can-i-get-user-image-url) to fix it. But that should not occur again because according to Google:

> this is fixed in 2.3.1 that we've just released.

See status on that bug [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/77).

And a suggestion, put your login success code inside a `if(!error)` clause. Right now you are assuming that a failure in login will never occur. (If you have already done that but didn't show it here then ignore this suggestion).

Comment: getting error as " Property 'imageURLWithDimension' not found on object of type 'GIDProfileData *'"

Comment: @karthi sorry about that typo. I have updated the code. It is a method not a property thats why the error. Should work now!